# How to do multiple auto-citation?

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

Kindly help me on how to do the multiple citation. I used natbib in MikTex.

Its autocite when I only cite a single reference like this `\citep{Howard1990}`

but if I want to add the other references to it, autocite won't work. `\citep{Howard1990,Ashley2001}`. The references for Ashley2001 does not appear auto when I type. Need help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by 'autocite'? Do you mean automatic completion of the the citatation key (i.e. 'Ashley2001') in the editor? If that is the case, you have to specify which editor you're using.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry if I used a wrong term. Im using TexMaker